# data.table + ecdf - undefined column

Tags: r, data.table, ecdf

I am working with `data.table`. It is easy to select a column from a `data.table` object:

```
> head(data.table(mtcars)[,2])
   cyl
1:   6
2:   6
3:   4
4:   6
5:   8
6:   6
```

But trying to select a column using this syntax within a `ecdf` call yields an error:

```
> ecdf(data.table(mtcars)[,2])(data.table(mtcars)[,2])
```

> Error in `[.data.frame`(x, i) : undefined columns selected

Can someone explain me **why** please?

Pragmatically, one way around this is to do:

```
> ecdf(data.table(mtcars)[[2]])(data.table(mtcars)[[2]])
 [1] 0.56250 0.56250 0.34375 0.56250 1.00000 0.56250 1.00000 0.34375 0.34375 0.56250 0.56250 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000
[17] 1.00000 0.34375 0.34375 0.34375 0.34375 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 0.34375 0.34375 0.34375 1.00000 0.56250 1.00000 0.34375
```

but I would like to understand the behavior above.

Comment: you can try `ecdf(unlist(data.table(mtcars)[,2]))`.  The `unlist` helps deal with the dataframe returned by the `data.table`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is in the extraction.  In the first case, it is still a a data.table, while in second case it is a `vector`

```
data.table(mtcars)[[2]]
#[1] 6 6 4 6 8 6 8 4 4 6 6 8 8 8 8 8 8 4 4 4 4 8 8 8 8 4 4 4 8 6 8 4
```

---

`data.table` and `data.frame` syntax are slightly different.  IN  `data.table`, the `[`, by default uses `drop = TRUE`.  So, using `,` and selecting only a single column will drop the dimensions to become a `vector`

It is also mentioned in the [data.table-faq](http://127.0.0.1:26463/library/data.table/doc/datatable-faq.html#j-num)

> For consistency so that when you use data.table in functions that
>   accept varying inputs, you can rely on DT[...] returning a data.table.
>   You don’t have to remember to include drop=FALSE like you do in
>   data.frame. data.table was first released in 2006 and this difference
>   to data.frame has been a feature since the very beginning.

Comment: You should write `vignette("whatever")` instead of a link (which happens to be to your local copy not a web one anyways). Also, I guess the drop comparison doesn't exactly fit: data.table acts more like `drop=FALSE`, while you wrote `TRUE`.